# jQuery UI Accordian. I need to make newly appended item active

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I would like the newly appended section to be active in a jQuery Accordion.

I have a link that appends new sections to the Accordion but currently it is not activating the newly added element as I wish.

```
$("#add-content-section").on("click", function(){

    var count = $("#accordion .content_section").size();
    var newsection = ++count;
     var html = '<h4 class="typo">Section '+newsection+'</h4><div class="content_section">Test</div>';

    $('#accordion').append(html).accordion('destroy').accordion({active: newsection});
  });
```

I have created a JSFiddle to demonstrate http://jsfiddle.net/stefairc/JP2wN/

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of destroying the accordion, you can [refresh](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#method-refresh) it.

Then you could simply trigger the click event.

```
$('#accordion').append(html).accordion('refresh').find('h4').last().click();
```

You could also do as `Ohgodwhy` suggested, and use the index.

```
var count = $('#accordion').find('h4').length;

// Then later inside your event handler
$('#accordion').append(html).accordion('refresh').accordion({active:count++});
```

Comment: Instead of `find('h2').last().click();` just do `var count = $('#accordion h2').length;` on DOM ready, then do `newinstance = count++;` and now `.accordion({active: newinstance})` will work fine in every click handler.

Comment: Hi ahren, I tried to use 'refresh' but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Ohgodwhy this is the method i have been trying to use but it doesn't work. Please check the JSFiddle link. Thanks!

Comment: @StevenFairclough - it does work. http://jsfiddle.net/JP2wN/1/  -- also your original method works if you `-1` off the count (since it's a zero-based index).

Answer (score 0):

Destroy accordion first, then inject html and initialize.

Using `active:-1` will activate last section

```
 $('#accordion').accordion('destroy').append(html).accordion({active:-1});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VmB6T/8/)**</kbd>

Comment: similarly `-2` for second last section